# Build Issue After Upgradingt to Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 | Navigation Directions

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack

I updated my IDE to Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 and I am getting build error. I don't now why. But they seems only related with **navigation-directions** from `Navigation`.

here is the screen shots

[image]

[image]

I couldn't find the solution for this on the internet so any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using?

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake, I am using 2.5.3